# Как в Python(или VB) вставить символ во весь столбец в txt файле? И аналогично - как заменить символ во всём столбце?

Tags: python, текст, visual-basic

Нужно например вставить точку как разделитель между 4-ым и 5-ым знаком во всех строках файла.
А так же поменять имеющийся разделитель например на 8 месте строки с точки на запятую (или любой другой знак) во всех строках.
И какой язык программирования из существующих самый быстрый для подобных операций?
Нужно обработать подобным образом TXT таблицы на сотни мегабайт-гигабайты.

Comment: мне кажется UNIX-оидные `awk`, `mawk`, `sed` и подобные гораздо лучше подходят для подобных манипуляций

Comment: К сожалению, я на винде (

Comment: @JohnSmith git bash, cygwin

Answer (score 0):

читать файл построчно, строку обработать и записать в результирующий файл. Примерно так:

```
with open('input.txt') as r, open('output.txt', 'w') as w:
    for line in r:  # если, извесны только позиции, для замены, в строке
        w.write(line[:5] + '.' + line[5:8] + ',' + line[9:])
```